# KDB/Q: Get sum of a certain column value

Tags: kdb

I want to create a column that equals the sum of the value in another column (`colA`) when the value of another column (`colB`) equal something.

Without the condition, I can get the sum of all values in `colA` by using:

```
update TotalVal: sum colB by date from myTable
```

I tried to achieve what I want by using

```
update GOT: sum colB by date from myTable where colA in (`abc,`edf)
```

This creates the correct values for `GOT`, but the `GOT` column only has value where `colA` is abc or edf. This is not what I really want.
To visualise, what I want is the column `WANTED`

```
date        colA    colB    GOT     WANTED
2020.08.17  abc     5       13      13
2020.08.17  mom     7               13
2020.08.17  xyz     8       13      13
2020.08.17  tuf     9               13
```

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it myself by

```
update (GOT: sum colB where colA in (`abc,`edf)) by date from myTable
```

Comment: Can get rid of some brackets: ``update GOT:sum colB where colA in `abc`def by date from myTable``

Comment: You could also shave a few characters using multiply instead of where, though this is situational: ```update GOT:sum colB*colA in`abc`xyz by date from t```

Comment: thanks, this is neat, how should i interpret the * in this case? does it have the same meaning as `WHERE`?

Comment: No - the false booleans will multiply the values by zero so then summing effectively only sums the ones which were true (since they would be multiplied by boolean 1). Only works for certain aggregations, `sum` being one of them